# How to use an unrestricted service token to restrict a service's access to a file

Tags: windows, security, access-token

Sue has a standard user account domain account on Windows 10 Pro. She has an application that can run from the command line or as a service. The service runs with her credentials. Using the SC command the service has been assigned an unrestricted sid (SERVICE_SID_TYPE:  UNRESTRICTED). The service name is NT SERVICE\MyService. I want to allow Sue full control of a file when running the program from the command line. I want the service to have Read Attributes and Read Extended Attributes access only.

Using the service account I adjusted the security settings on the file by denying the service all access except for Read Attributes and Read Extended Attributes. I added a second entry that gave it Read Attributes and Read Extended Attributes permission. I've confirmed these are the settings by viewing the Effective Access settings in the Advanced Security Settings dialog box: all of the rows in the Effective Access column contain Xs except for Read Attributes and Read Extended Attributes. They have checkboxes. The rows with Xs have "File Permissions" as their "Access limited by" column.

Still the service is able to change the files permissions. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any pointers. I'm open to other approaches to achieving the results I'm after.

Comment: Have you checked who the file's owner is?  The owner can always change the permissions, regardless of the ACL.

Comment: Yes. The file owner is administrator. Sue has full control of the file. I went further and denied the service any access to the file. The SC showsid command indicates the STATUS is Active. icacls for the file shows [SUE: (I)(F)  MyService:(N)] I intended to give MyService no access to the file.

Comment: Is it really in that order?  The deny entry should be at the top of the list.

Comment: Also, you can use Process Explorer, available from the MS web site, to double-check the service's token.  Refer to the "Security" tab.

Comment: I'll try Process Explorer. icacls shows 

    NT SERVICE\MyService:(N)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
    DOM\sue:(I)(F)
    DOM\Administrator:(I)(F)

Comment: Process Explorer shows Sue's SID. According to an MSDN article the per-service SID is added to the process token but it doesn't appear in Process Explorer.

Comment: After denying any access to the service (as above) it can't open the file for reading but it can delete it. If I remove the service from the access list completely it can open the file also.

Comment: Sounds as though the service SID *is* in the token, or changing the permissions like that wouldn't have any effect.  Deleting the file is a special case, you will need to restrict access to the directory (specifically, the "delete child" right) as well as to the file in order to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

The per-service SID was working properly. After reviewing [Harry's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886887/harry-johnston) comments and checking the containing folder permissions I got things working. Thanks a lot Harry.